# Modifying a Calendar Event in iOS or iPadOS

Tags: ios, calendar, ipados, timezone

As far as I’m aware, even in iOS 17 I can’t set a calendar event’s timezone to floating. I know I can do it on macOS, but that’s not always convenient, especially when I’m overseas, which is the whole problem.

I’m resigned to the fact that I’ll have to write something, but before I do, I would like to check whether I’ve overlooked something. Here are the possibilities:

- using an apple shortcut. I can some calendar actions but the timezone is not included.
- writing an action. I don’t think calendar events support actions — I certainly can’t see any when I edit an event.
- writing an app. I have some swift skills, though it’s not my strength. I imagine I’ll have to work out how to select a date/event from the application just to set the timezone.

There’s nothing on the App store that I can find, but I don’t think it would be too hard to do.

Is there a shortcut option or action or some other alternative that I have missed?